# Using JsonSerializer with MemoryMappedViewStream " '0x00' is invalid after a single JSON value."

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json, memory-mapped-files

I am passing data between processes using Memory Mapped Files. Both processes are .NET 6.0 applications which share a .dll containing the data class. I had been serializing the data using `BinaryFormatter` for years but am now working to replace it as it is deprecated. I am trying to serialize the data using `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` instead. Example class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleDataSource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Using `MemoryMappedViewStream` with `JsonSerializer` isn't working though. As a test I am just serializing an object and then deserializing it back to another instance:

```
string dataFilePath = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
using (MemoryMappedFile dataFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(dataFilePath, 104857600, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (MemoryMappedViewStream dataStream = dataFile.CreateViewStream())
{
    SimpleDataSource original = new SimpleDataSource
    {
        Name = "Example Name",
        Date = new DateTime(1999, 12, 31),
        Number = 191
    };

    JsonSerializer.Serialize(dataStream, original);
    dataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    SimpleDataSource deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SimpleDataSource>(dataStream);
}
```

This throws the following Exception upon deserialization:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: '0x00' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 65.

This error is unique to `MemoryMappedViewStream`. If I replace `dataStream` in the example with a simple `MemoryStream` it deserializes without issue.

Comment: Try adding `dataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` to the stream BEFORE serializing.

Comment: @PoulBak tried it, same result.

Comment: What happens if you close the view stream, then open a new one at the same location?

Comment: Also, does the underlying `MemoryMappedFile` contain additional data past the end of the just-serialized JSON content?  Or might there be additional stuff beyond that?

Comment: @dbc Closing the view stream and opening a new one from the MemoryMappedFile has the same result. Not aware of additional content, I updated the question with example of how the file is being created.

Comment: ' Expected end of data' indicates that the `0x00` comes after the reel data (which shouldn't happen). Try to save the  contents in a file and open it with a binary viewer.

Comment: @PoulBak that could be the issue. When I open it I see a bunch of null bytes after the serialized object - probably caused by using a constant for the MemoryMappedFile?

Comment: It tries to read to the end of the stream. JSON.Net would get it right. I assume you cannot size the MemoryMappedFile each time (since it's *shared*), so you probably need your own `Utf8JsonReader` (which does not work with a StreamReader *directly*, while `JsonTextReader` does)

Comment: @PoulBak @Jimi based on your comments I tried trimming the trailing zero-bytes from the end of the stream and copying into a new `byte[]` before deserializing, and it worked. Seems I'll need to write a method to sanitize the data before deserialization since I use fixed length files.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround, seems this is a bug in `MemoryMappedFile` implemantation (or the `JsonSerializer`).

Comment: You can just probably slice the content of a StreamReader, something like: `ReadOnlySpan<char> span = null; using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 8192, true)) { span = reader.ReadToEnd().AsSpan(); } var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SimpleDataSource>(span.Slice(0, span.IndexOf(char.MinValue)));` -- @PoulBak There's no bug in either, it's just behavior. You might say that JsonSerializer *could* identify the end of the string by itself

Comment: @Jimi I say:  Should!

Comment: It could be simpler, as, e.g., `byte bt; var ms = new MemoryStream(); while ((bt = (byte)dataStream.ReadByte()) > 0) { ms.WriteByte(bt); } var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SimpleDataSource>(ms.ToArray().AsSpan());`